# To Make A Function Or Not To Make A Function

Tags: c++, coding-style

Note: For this question I will mainly be referring to C++, however this may apply to other languages.

Note: Please assume there is no recursion.

People often say (if you have an exceptionally large function) to "break up" a function into several smaller 
functions, but is this logical? What if I know for a fact that I will never use one of those smaller functions, 
that is just a  waste of: memory, performance, and you may have to jump around the code more when reading it. 
Also what if you are only going to use a (hypothetically large) function once, should you just insert the
function body into the place where it would be called (for the same reasons as last time i.e: memory, performance, and you may have to jump around the code more when reading it)? So... to make a function or not to make a function, that is the question.

**TO ALL**
**EDIT**

I am still going through all the answers, however from what I have read so far I have formed a hypothesis.

Would it be correct to say split it up functions during development, but do what I suggest in the question before deployment, along with making functions you use once in development, but inserting bodies before deployment?

Comment: You forgot one criterion: readability.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth My argument for that was: "you may have to jump around the code more when reading it".

Comment: With any modern IDE, that's not an issue.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It could be if your tracking what 6 different functions do.

Comment: It really isn't, and certainly not when compared to having those 6 functions manually inlined into a single uber-function.  Put simply, inlining functions is usually terrible for readability.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Even if they weren't for say "Derp The Programmer" it may be hard to read your code.

Comment: Also, if you're having to keep track of what 6 functions do simultaneously, then the author has probably refactored badly (or named the functions in an unhelpful way).  The whole point is to minimise the need to keep track of multiple levels of abstraction simultaneously.

Comment: To your edit: no absolutely not.  You should never run different code in development/test and in production.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth
First Comment: Well 6 is a bit of an exaggeration (even though I made it), that makes sense though.
Second Comment: Even if you keep the dev - code and test the deploy code?

Comment: I say, more often than not, to make functions. They should be small well defined tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on the context.

When we say the size of a function, we actually mean the semantic distance of lines inside the function. We prefer that one function should do only one thing. If your function only does one thing and semantic distance is small inside it, then it is OK to have large function.

However, it is not good practice to make a function do a lot of things and it is better to refactor such functions to a few smaller ones with good naming and good placement of codes, such that the user of the code does not need to jump around.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much about performance and memory. Your compiler should take care of the bulk of that for you, especially for very thin functions.

My goal is typically to ensure that the given function call can be replaced entirely in the reader's memory--the developer can treat the abstraction purely. Take this:

```
// Imagine here that these are real variable/function names as written by a
// lazy coder. I have seen code like this in the wild.
void someFunc(int arg1, int arg2) {
  int val3 = doFirstPart(arg1, field1);
  int val4 = doSecondPart(arg2, val3);
  queue.push(val4);
}
```

The refactoring of doFirstPart and doSecondPart buys you very little, and likely makes things harder to understand. The problem here isn't method extraction, though: The problem is poor naming and abstraction! You will have to read `doFirstPart` and `doSecondPart` or the point of the whole function is lost.

Consider this, instead:

```
void pushLatestRateAndValue(int rate, int value) {
  int rateIndex = calculateRateIndex(rate, latestRateTable);
  int valueIndex = caludateValueIndex(rateIndex, value);
  queue.push(valueIndex);
}
```

In this contrived example, you don't have to read `calculateRateIndex` or `calculateValueIndex` unless you really want to dig deep--you know exactly what it does just by reading it.

Aside from that, it may be a matter of personal style. I know that some coders prefer to extract every business "statement" into a different function, but I find that a little hard to read. My personal preference is to look for an opportunity to extract a function from any function longer than one "screenful" (~25 lines) which has the advantage of keeping the entire  function visible at once, and also because 25 lines happens to my personal mental limit of short-term memory and temporary understanding.

Answer (score 1):

There are many good arguments for not making a routine longer than roughly what will fit on one page. One that most people don't always think about is that - unless you deploy debug symbols, which most people don't do - that stack trace coming in from the field is a lot easier to analyze and turn into a hypothesis about a cause when the routines that it refers to are small than when the error turn out to be occuring somewhere in that 2,000-line whale of a method that you never got around to split up.

Comment: Isent' this a little contradictory?

Comment: You say you typically do not include debugging symbols in your code, then you make an argument saying that re - factoring a larger function up into smaller functions is easier to debug, no statement was made after this, suggesting that you would ship code like this.

Comment: Yeah, I see why that statement might not make a lot of sense if you're a C++ programmer. Most of the stuff I do is deployed on .NET, however, which is able to generate a stack trace of method calls leading up to an error even without explicit debug information deployed.